# Google OAuth2.0, How to implement password confirmation?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Whenever a user wants to delete something in my system, they're required to confirm their password. Is it possible to do that using Google OAuth2.0? I want to have a modal that has password field and send the request to Google API.

I checked the documentation already there's no API for this, is there any other ways around?

Comment: what's you're using for Google OAuth, have you checked Firebase to add Google Auth to your app

Comment: @Karim I didn't use firebase. I use [https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2] (Google Identity)

Comment: if you're using OAuth2 then you gonna have to implement it yourself because Google have their own way to force user to enter a password you can't force google to force a user to enter a password, unless you're using Google Business